# Extracting digits with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string : `[{"Weight":70,"CustomerId":45},{"Weight":30,"CustomerId":733‌​}]`
please note that quotation marks are parts of this string
I need to extract the digits for 'weight' and 'customerId' separately.
I tried to do it like this for weight :

`MatchCollection Weightmatches = Regex.Matches(r["Formula"].ToString(), @"""Weight"":(\d+),");`

(there might be more Weight or Customer numbers on this string)

but I can't seem to understand how to isolate the numbers alone.

please help!!

Comment: You should not use a regex to parse JSON, in C#, use JSON.NET to do that.

Comment: Note that it is not yet clear what output you need.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand: do you want to get a list of KeyValuePairs with Wieght as keys and CustomerId as values? `var results = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();`?

Comment: yes, I thought about tuple<int,int> at first . but this is a better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly parse JSON, it is recommended to use a JSON parser. JSON.NET provides one, just install it as a NuGet package and use the following code:

```
var json_data = "[{\"Weight\":70,\"CustomerId\":45},{\"Weight\":30,\"CustomerId\":733}]";
dynamic parsedObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_data);
var results = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
foreach (dynamic entry in parsedObject)
{
    if (entry.Weight != null && entry.CustomerId != null)
        results.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(int.Parse(entry.Weight.ToString()), int.Parse(entry.CustomerId.ToString())));
}
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a `JSON` parser is the right answer here. But I suppose you *could* do a Regex **search** similar to this:

```
(?:["][^"]+["] : (\d+))
```

Or if you want to capture the text as well:

```
(?:["]([^"]+)["] : (\d+))
```

Comment: can you please write the full line? something is not clear to me with the syntax

Comment: @Jonathan: Do not use regex, please. Do you want me to post a JSON.NET based solution? It is not really that difficult, and is much more readable.

Comment: @Jonathan: Then please share the full JSON data in the question as your current string is not a valid JSON.

Comment: [{"Weight":70,"CustomerId":45},{"Weight":30,"CustomerId":733}]

Comment: Please add it to the question and specify what output you need.